# how to install kernel headers for fedora 22 - without networking

Tags: drivers, fedora

I'm trying to get a useful Fedora 22 installation running on my Lenovo yoga 3 pro Laptop.

I have done a full fedora installation to a USB3 flash drive, and it runs well, but I don't have any networking. I purchased a D-Link DUB1312 USB Ethernet adapter, but discovered I need to compile drivers for this. I downloaded the driver source and tried to make. Here i discovered I needed to kernel-devel sources.

So I switched to windows and downloaded to USB what looked like the right package from here: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/29666225/dir/fedora_22/com/kernel-devel-4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64.rpm.html

Switched back to Fedora, mounted the USB drive, and tried to install the package:

```
[root@localhost DUB-1312_A1_Linux_Driver_v1.4.0]# dnf install /mnt/kernel-devel-4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64.rpm 
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora' from 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-22&arch=x86_64': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-22&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]
```

I don't exacctly understand what's happening here, but clearly looks like dnf is trying to connect to the internet - I have no internet connectivity.

So, I'm kind of stuck. I can't build the driver for my USB Etnerenet adapter without kernel-devel. Any hints here on how to install the kernel-devel package from USB drive without networking?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the --disablerepo argument for dnf. It looks like dnf comes configured out of the box to search for "fedora" and "updates" repos.
The command that worked for me was:
    # dnf --disablerepo fedora --disablerepo updates install kernel-devel-4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64.rpm

Note that I then needed to install GCC, and binutils, etcetra. In the end I discovered I could tether to my android phone and get connectivity through USB and the phone's wifi. All went smoothly after that.